# Unable to convert a webpage to an html file where all the links will be absolute links

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I've created a script which is able to convert a webpage to an html file so that the file looks very similar to that webpage. The only issue that I can't fix is that the html file contains relative urls, as in `/organizations/11-unilever?group=8831` whereas the absolute link is `https://en.eyeka.com/organizations/11-unilever?group=8831`.

I've tried with:

```
import requests

link = "https://en.eyeka.com/contests/8831/results"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
    
    with open("results.html", "wb") as f:
        f.write(res.content)
```

> How can I convert the webpage to an html file where all the links are absolute links (full links)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer includes additional libraries, but it doesn't make the assumption that it will only work with the example url you provided. It also doesn't assume that all urls are relative.

```
import requests
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://en.eyeka.com/contests/8831/results"

with requests.Session() as s:
    headers = {"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"}
    s.headers = headers
    res = s.get(link)

u = urlparse(res.url)
domain = u.scheme + "://" + u.netloc  # extract domain will work with http or https since we are also extracting the scheme
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.content, "html.parser")

for a in soup.find_all('a'):  # loop through all links
    if "href" in a.attrs:  # not all links have an href tag
        if "http" not in a.attrs['href']:  # not all links are relative links
            a.attrs['href'] = domain + a.attrs['href']

with open("results.html", "w", encoding='utf-8') as f:
    f.write(str(soup))
```

Comment: It seems to duplicate the base url in the contributor section, but that content is generated via javascript so it's unclear why. To fix it perhaps you could remove the base url in the json object that contains the user/url pairs.

Comment: This doesn't modify the scripts, stylesheets, links and other making the page unusable locally.

Comment: @rafalou38 the scripts and stylesheets use absolute links. If you run the code, it does work locally.

Answer (score 2):

I checked the page you linked and I suggest you check for all the 'href="/' the script will find in the page and replace them with 'href="https://en.eyeka.com/'

so:

```
string_html.replace('href="/', 'href="https://en.eyeka.com/')
```

Something like this.

```
import requests

link = "https://en.eyeka.com/contests/8831/results"

with requests.Session() as s:
    s.headers['user-agent'] = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36'
    res = s.get(link)
# convert to string
    res = res.text
# add https ...
    res = res.replace('href="/', 'href="https://en.eyeka.com/')
# encode 
    res = res.encode()  
    with open("results.html", "wb") as f:
        f.write(res)
```

Since they are relative paths they cannot be anything else than https://en.eyeka.com/ + the relative path.

Comment: I tried your solution and ended up getting this error `f.write(res.content)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'content'`.

Comment: That's because res is converted into a string 3 lines prior so it no longer has 'content'. Code won't work as is.

Comment: Your code still isn't going to work. I would suggest running your code.

Comment: check again please

Answer (score 2):

You could use a regex to find and replace relative URLs:

```py
import re
import requests
import urllib3

link = "https://en.eyeka.com/contests/8831/results"

with requests.Session() as s:
    base_url = "://".join(
        urllib3.get_host(link)[:2]
    )  # get the base url (https://en.eyeka.com)

    s.headers[
        "user-agent"
    ] = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.150 Safari/537.36"

    text = s.get(link).text

    text = re.sub(
        r"(href=[\"\'])\/", f"\g<1>{base_url}/", text, 0, re.MULTILINE
    )  # replace all relative urls with absolute

    with open("results.html", "w", encoding="utf-8") as f:
        f.write(text)
```

Comment: I tested your script just now. It appears that the links have been converted to absolute links but this is what i see when I hover the cursor over [that link](https://imgur.com/XUM0zS1) and as a result when I click on such links, they lead to wrong address.

Comment: Sorry I had forgotten the `:`, fixed!